# Unable to export dynamic Oracle table to properly formatted CSV using sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to substitute a Python/pandas export process and go direct from Oracle to csv. I have seen a couple of posts such as this one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53576681/properly-formatting-tables-in-sqlplus)

Suppose I have a table in Oracle with three columns: ColA, ColB, ColC. I want to employ a command line utility that takes as input an SQL command and generates a CSV file that would look like any standard CSV file with a header line and rows of values:

```
ColA,ColB,ColC
A,B,C
D,E,F
...
```

In SQL Server, there is a utility called bcp I can use which looks like this:

```
bcp "SELECT 'ColA', 'ColB', 'ColC' UNION ALL Select ColA, ColB, ColC From 
myTable" queryout "C:\Temp\csvfiles\output.csv" -c -CRAW -S localhost -u 
my_userid -p my_password -d my_database
```

Easy-peasy. But in looking for the Oracle equivalent, not so much.

I took a look [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:88212348059) but the author wants you to create a UTL_FILE. That doesn't seem like a possibility since this is supposed to be a completely generic process that gets built and run from Python. I took a look at sqlplus but I can't seem to come up with a way to create a typical CSV similar to bcp. The docs [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14357/ch6.htm#i1081036) weren't terribly clear on this either. It's such a common format I expected to see tons of examples.

Sites like this [here](https://chartio.com/resources/tutorials/how-to-write-to-a-csv-file-using-oracle-sql-plus/)  show how to output a fixed-length CSV using sqlplus but don't show you how to add a header row and values are padded, which might be OK, but not desirable. This was about the best I could come up with:

```
set colsep ,
set headsep off
set pagesize 0
set trimspool on
set linesize 200
set numwidth 50
SET TERMOUT OFF

Spool output.csv

SELECT ColA,
    ColB,
    ColC
FROM MyTable;

Spool off
exit
```

So, is there an equivalent tool/command in Oracle to the trusty bcp, or is there a sample somewhere using sqlplus that can generate a csv similar to the one above with a header line and without all the leading spaces? Or is there another option to generate dynamic CSV files from random Oracle tables? Or am I stuck using Python, pyodbc and pandas to get my nicely-formatted CSV files? TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle's SQLcl utility(commandline  executable `sql` or `sql.exe`) could help you achieve it.

Here's the download link [**SQLcl**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sqlcl/downloads/index.html). It's free.

In order to export a file in the CSV format, you may simply specify

```
SET SQLFORMAT CSV
```

If you want a different delimiter, use

```
SET SQLFORMAT DELIMITED '|'
```

Here's a sample output with the header

```
SQL> select * from employees;
"EMPLOYEE_ID","FIRST_NAME","LAST_NAME","EMAIL","PHONE_NUMBER","HIRE_DATE","JOB_ID","SALARY","COMMISSION_PCT","MANAGER_ID","DEPARTMENT_ID"
    198,"Donald","OConnell","DOCONNEL","650.507.9833",21-06-07,"SH_CLERK",2600,,124,50
    199,"Douglas","Grant","DGRANT","650.507.9844",13-01-08,"SH_CLERK",2600,,124,50
    200,"Jennifer","Whalen","JWHALEN","515.123.4444",17-09-03,"AD_ASST",4400,,101,10
    201,"Michael","Hartstein","MHARTSTE","515.123.5555",17-02-04,"MK_MAN",13000,,100,20
    202,"Pat","Fay","PFAY","603.123.6666",17-08-05,"MK_REP",6000,,201,20
    203,"Susan","Mavris","SMAVRIS","515.123.7777",07-06-02,"HR_REP",6500,,101,40
    204,"Hermann","Baer","HBAER","515.123.8888",07-06-02,"PR_REP",10000,,101,70
    205,"Shelley","Higgins","SHIGGINS","515.123.8080",07-06-02,"AC_MGR",12008,,101,110
    206,"William","Gietz","WGIETZ","515.123.8181",07-06-02,"AC_ACCOUNT",8300,,205,110
    100,"Steven","King","SKING","515.123.4567",17-06-03,"AD_PRES",24000,,,90
    101,"Neena","Kochhar","NKOCHHAR","515.123.4568",21-09-05,"AD_VP",17000,,100,90
    102,"Lex","De Haan","LDEHAAN","515.123.4569",13-01-01,"AD_VP",17000,,100,90
    103,"Alexander","Hunold","AHUNOLD","590.423.4567",03-01-06,"IT_PROG",9000,,102,60
    104,"Bruce","Ernst","BERNST","590.423.4568",21-05-07,"IT_PROG",6000,,103,60
    105,"David","Austin","DAUSTIN","590.423.4569",25-06-05,"IT_PROG",4800,,103,60
    106,"Valli","Pataballa","VPATABAL","590.423.4560",05-02-06,"IT_PROG",4800,,103,60
    107,"Diana","Lorentz","DLORENTZ","590.423.5567",07-02-07,"IT_PROG",4200,,103,60
    108,"Nancy","Greenberg","NGREENBE","515.124.4569",17-08-02,"FI_MGR",12008,,101,100
    109,"Daniel","Faviet","DFAVIET","515.124.4169",16-08-02,"FI_ACCOUNT",9000,,108,100
```

Additionally, all the SQL* Plus commands are supported with few more specific to SQLcl. See this [command line reference](https://docs.oracle.com/database/sql-developer-17.4/SQCQR/toc.htm#SQCQR-GUID-6736ADCE-ABD9-49B8-91E5-7973221DC434)

Answer (score 0):

SET MARKUP CSV ON - use this in sqlplus before executing the query to get the data in csv format